# Is it possible to place several divs of unknown height in the centre of a parent div using css?

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="parent" style="border:1px solid #666;width:600px;height:200px;padding:5px;">
<div id="child1" style="border:1px solid #666;float:left;margin-left:10px;display:inline-block;">How<br>are<br>you?</div>
<div id="child2" style="border:1px solid #666;float:left;margin-left:100px;">How are you?</div>
<div id="child3" style="border:1px solid #666;float:right;margin-right:40px;">How are you?<br>How are you?<br>How are you?</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to place the three child divs at the center of the parent div to make something like the following screenshot?

[image: Example Image]

The height of child divs may change as the text inside changes, so it is not possible to use the properites `top`, `margin-top` and `position:absolute` to position the child divs at the center because the height of the child divs is not fixed, and as the height changes one would have to constantly change the value `margin-top`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: hmm... have you tried using percentage % instead of pixels px? or a margin 0 auto

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/hcLwtLye), if that's what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HI now you can try to this way :-

`display: table`  and `display:table-cell` **property** as like this

```css
#parent{
display:table;
  width:100%;
}
#child1, #child2, #child3{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  border:solid 1px red;
  width:33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="child1">How<br>are<br>you?</div>
<div id="child2">How are you?</div>
<div id="child3">How are you?<br>How are you?<br>How are you?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic flexbox recreation of the image you posted. Hopefully it's similar to what you're looking for!

**Screenshot:**

[image: Flexbox layout]

**Live Demo:**

```css
#parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border:1px solid #666;
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    padding:5px;
}
.child {
    align-self: center;
}

.child > div {
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child" id="child1"><div>How
        <br />are
        <br />you?</div></div>
    <div class="child" id="child2"><div>How are you?</div></div>
    <div class="child" id="child3"><div>How are you?
        <br />How are you?
        <br />How are you?</div></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/hsrfxdo7/